# Entity Framework hides inherited member Warning

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

I have For Example Product and a ProductDetail Table. Where in Model Product is a base class for ProductDetail. There is a ProductName in ProductDetail. Everything is working fine but I wanted to know that why the EF is giving me this warning and how to remove this. I tried updating Designer.cs with a `new` keyword was just keen to see what happens but it removes it as soon as it is compiled.

Googled it out but did not find any relevant information. So m here asking a question if anybody knows how to deal with this warning.

The Warning which I get is here:

```
  DataLayer.ProductDetail.ProductName' hides inherited member
 'Product.ProductName'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't have 2 properties (columns) ProductName? How did you setup the inheritance?

Comment: I have just imported the table basically both have a primary key as productId but in the ProductDetail its a foreign key.

Comment: And do both tables have a ProductName column? (They shouldn't).

Comment: No Product does not have ProductName

Comment: Re-check your mappings et,. this shouldn't be happening. The error indicates taht there is a 'Product.ProductName' property.

Comment: I checked it and it is because its partial class and access is public if we make it internal warning is gone but gets me different erros... We need it public because you may know we need it for objects around the applications.

Comment: Product is a Base AbstractClass

Comment: `partial` is not the problem and not the solution. But I don't get the `abstract class Product`. Is it based on a table or not?

Comment: Yes its table but i have several other entities linked to it and made a datalayer also partial class so product is abstract because other classes implement the methods defined in that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is generic C# warning. If you have a base class that has a member with the same name as one in the child class, you will get this warning. It is basically telling you to be careful, as ProductName might not refer to what you expect.

In this particular case, if you set ProductName on ProductDetail, then the ProductName on the Product class will *not* be set. Depending on your mapping, this may or may not be an issue.

Erick

Comment: I know but its an auto generated  EF model that is why i am asking. I tried it with new that overrides but some how EF designer removes that on compiling.

Comment: It did some how work today. Yesterday dont know it delted my new keyword. I knew it but still you get the credit. Thanks for the Reply.